# Lebesgue product measure when $A \subseteq [1,0]^2$.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am struggling with this question. It doesn't seem like it should be to tricky, but I am having difficulty with what the definition of $A$ is.

> Let $A^x = \{y \in [0,1] : (x,y) \in A \}$.
>
> It is given that $\lambda (A^x) \leq \frac{1}{4}$ for each $ x \in \mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$, and $\lambda(A^x) \geq 3/4$ for each $x \in [0,1] \setminus \mathbb{Q} $. Which one of the following statements are true. Justify your answer.
>
> 1. $\ $ $\lambda_2(A) \leq \frac{1}{4}$,
> 2. $\ $  $\frac{1}{4} \leq \lambda_2(A) \leq \frac{3}{4}$,
> 3. $\ $ $\lambda_2(A) \geq \frac{3}{4}$.

Here $\lambda$ is the Lesbesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\lambda_2 = \lambda \otimes \lambda$ is the Lebesgue product measure defined on $\mathbb{R}^2 = \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} $.

From the question I gather that $\lambda(x)=1$, therefore it seems as though $\lambda(y)=1$ so the third option. Help!

Comment: Typo in (iii). $\leq$ must be $\geq$.

Comment: I would have guessed $\lambda_2 A \ge {3 \over 4}$. Fubini is your friend.

Comment: What do you mean by $\lambda(x) = 1$???

Comment: I don't understand your notation in your last sentence.

Comment: If something is measurable then surely $\lambda(x)=x\cap\mathbb{Q} + x \setminus \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: This is an old past paper question and fubini's theorem wasn't on the course!

Comment: You need the additional hypothesis that $A$ is Lebesgue measurable in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\lambda_2(A)=\iint1_A(x,y)\lambda(dy)\lambda(dx)=\iint1_{A^x}(y)\lambda(dy)\lambda(dx)=$$$$\int\lambda(A^x)\lambda(dy)\geq\int_{[0,1]\setminus\mathbb Q}\frac34\lambda(dy)=\frac34\lambda([0,1]\setminus\mathbb Q)=\frac34\times1=\frac34$$

Answer (score 0):

The map $\chi_A: [0,1]^2\to\mathbb R$ where $$\chi_A(x,y) = \begin{cases}1,&(x,y)\in A\\0,& (x,y)\notin A\end{cases}$$ is nonnegative, bounded above by $1$, and is defined on a compact set. Hence by Tonelli's theorem we compute
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb R^2} \chi_A \ \mathsf d(x\times y) &= \int_{[0,1]} \int_{[0,1]} \chi_{A_x}\ \mathsf dx\ \mathsf dy\\
&\geqslant \int_{[0,1]}\int_{[0,1]} \chi_{A_x\setminus\mathbb Q}\ \mathsf dx\ \mathsf dy\\
&\geqslant \frac34 \int_{[0,1]} \mathsf dy\\
&=\frac34.
\end{align}